# Событие перемещения мыши

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

Как узнать в какую сторону относительно элемента повели мышь, меня интересует только ось Х.

Answer (score 2):

Повесить на mousemove элемента (или окна, если курсор движется рядом) функцию сохранения и сверки координат курсора. По-моему, это уже было реализовано [Aleko](http://studioad.ru/blog/2009-07-15-78). Посмотрите, подходит для вашей задачи?

Comment: Да спасибо это то что я хотел, постараюсь переписать на jquery)